# Adding div to IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, html, append

This code isn't working in IE, why not?

```
$('body').append('<div id="iedialog"><h2 class="dialog-header">Alert!</h2><div class="dialog-container"><center>It looks like you are using Internet Explorer! Please switch to another browser to use all our Designer features. We recommend Firefox (<a href="www.firefox.com">www.firefox.com</a>) and Google Chrome (<a href="www.google.com/chrome">www.google.com/chrome</a>) for an overall better internet experience.<br /><br /><input type="button" value="OK" id="okiedialog"></center>');
```

And yet if I copy and paste this exact code in the console, it works.

Comment: Maybe you invoke this before body is created?

Comment: When are you running the above code?

Comment: By golly, you're right! I put this code just before the body tag. It's working now. Do you want to put that as an answer so I can select it?

Comment: You recommend they get Firefox *and* Chrome? Anyway just redirect them to this page: http://www.browserchoice.eu/BrowserChoice/browserchoice_en.htm

Comment: thanks - that should be an "or", not an "and". wow... i haven't even hard of some of the browsers on that page. i don't think i would recommend something i haven't tested on.. are all of these other browsers better than IE?

Answer (score 1):

I'll point out you several problems that your code has. The markup being appended is invalid. It is seen when it is decomposed.

1) Your code is not closed properly

```
<div id="iedialog">
    <h2 class="dialog-header">Alert!</h2>
    <div class="dialog-container">
        <center>
            It looks like you are using Internet Explorer! Please switch to another browser to use all our Designer features. We recommend Firefox (<a href="www.firefox.com">www.firefox.com</a>) and Google Chrome 
            (
                <a href="www.google.com/chrome">www.google.com/chrome</a>
            ) 
            for an overall better internet experience.
            <br />
            <br />
            <input type="button" value="OK" id="okiedialog">
        </center>
```

Your `input` tag is not closed, your `div`s with class `dialog-container` and id `iedialog` is not closed.

1) Your markup uses a deprecated tag `center`. Get rid of it and try again.

Comment: thanks for noting! I'll fix that. But the main problem was that I had this script before the body tag.